# DIsplaying SQL BLOB field with image with javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html, image, blob

i have a problem with the following sql code.

```
output.dataBack.forEach(e => {
        let blob = new Blob(e.Pic.data, {type: "image/jpg"});
        let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        // let objektURL = URL.createObjectURL(e.Pic.data[0]);
        document.getElementById('contentOverview').appendChild(div);
        div.setAttribute('class', 'contentSub');
        div.appendChild(img);
        console.log(e.Pic);
        div.onclick = function() {
          window.location.href='product?id='+ e.ZUTATENNR +'';
        }
        console.log(url);
        img.src = url;
      });
```

If i want to display the image ("Pic") in html i can't see it.

Comment: The type "image/jpg" is not a valid MIME type,. Use "image/jpeg" instead.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is still the same.